# Azure SQL virtual machine performance - Inserts very slow

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying out different pricing tiers on SQL Server.

Im inserting 4000 rows distributed over 4 tables in 10 seconds

My problem: I don't any performance improvements from a small D2S_V3 to D8S_V3

My application need to insert many rows (bulking is not an option), and this kind of performance is not acceptable

I wonder why I dont see improvements.

So my noob question: Do I need to configure something to see improvements? My naive thinking says I should some difference :-)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the schema of your database? How do you insert rows? Do you have indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your schema, it looks like you are storage bound or network bound.
Storage:
Try to mount the database to the local (temporary disk) and see if you notice any difference, if it is faster then your bottleneck is the mounted disk.

Network bound:
Where is the client that's inserting these transaction? On same machine? On Azure?
I suggest you setup a client in the same region and do the tests.

Answer (score 0):

> inserting 4000 rows distributed over 4 tables in 10 seconds.I don't any performance improvements from a small D2S_V3 to D8S_V3

I would approach this problem using wait stats approach rather than throwing hardware first with out knowing problem..

For example,running below insert

```
insert into #t
select orderid from orders o
join
Customers c
on c.custid=o.custid
```

showed me below wait stats

> Wait WaitType="SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD" WaitTimeMs="1" WaitCount="167" 
>   Wait WaitType="PAGEIOLATCH_SH" WaitTimeMs="12" WaitCount="3" />
>   Wait WaitType="MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT" WaitTimeMs="21" WaitCount="4975" />

most of the time, the query spent time on

**PAGEIOLATCH_SH:**
getting data from disk into memory
**MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT** :allocating memory for the query to run

based on this i will try to troubleshoot by seeing if i have memory pressure on my system,since this query is trying to get data from disk.

This is just one example,but hopefully this will give you an idea..

Further i will try to see if select is returing data fast

Answer (score 0):

Performance can be directly linked to your hardware or configuration, but it's more likely that it has to do with the structures and the queries. Take a look at the execution plan for the INSERT operation to see how it is being resolved by the optimizer. Also, capture the query metrics using extended events to see how many resources are being used by the operation. These are more likely to lead to a resolution on why the query is performing slowly and enable you to scale the hardware to best serve the query.